# JQuery selectors do not find objects added via append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Long after a page has loaded (e.g. a minute or more), we can receive push messages which would cause us to append new content. After doing this when we query using Jquery hash selector it never returns the newly added content. In all cases, the length is always zero. We can see the content, but the selector returns nothing.

```
var section = '<section id="NewSection">Hello</section>';
$('.container').append(section);

if ($('#NewSection').length == 0)
{
    alert('This should not be zero at this point... Why is it?');
}
```

Is there something we need to do in order to enable JQuery to find the appended content after it is appended?

Comment: why `!`in your condition?

Comment: So you're saying the `alert()` shows up? That's what would happen if none are found. But then the message in the alert doesn't make much sense. I'd expect `"None were found"` to reflect the condition.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Could be coerecing the `length` to a boolean, same thing as `$('#NewSection').length === 0`

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run

Comment: Joey, presumably the code in the question sits inside an event handler. It'shard to know exactly what's going on without seeing that handler.

Answer (score 1):

> Thou shall not cast when not necesairly.

You're casting to boolean using `!`, See this cold run:

`len = $('#NewSection').length`

CASE `len = 0`
then `!len = true`

```
if(1){
    // code excecutes
}
```

---

CASE `len = 1`
then `!len = false`

```
if(0){
    // no code executes
}
```

---

In order work, you should rework your condition.

```
// @updated!
var section = '<section id="NewSection">Hello</section>';
$('.container').append(section);
if ($('#NewSection').length > 0) // meaning one or MORE than one element got selected
{
    alert('I should have found this!');
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0m5jj1u/)

Comment: Yes, we all fell for that one once. This is the proper solution!

Comment: OP's `if (!$('#NewSection').length)` is absolutely fine. I don't think this is about the construction of the test.

Comment: if `$('#NewSection').length` returns 1, it'll be casted to boolean true, then to false (due to `!`) and code wont execute.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: I don't see how it can be about anything else; OP just got the test backward.

Comment: @josegomezr: The problem isn't casting, it's just logic. Also: *"CASE len = 0 then !len = 1"* No, `!len` is `true`, not `1`.

Comment: Yes, but the alert reads "I should have found this!", which to me means, "I *should* have found this ... but didn't".

Comment: @josegomezr I have changed the logic but the underlying issue remains the same... Appended Ids are still not ever found. Length is always zero for appended items. Keep in mind that these are appended long after the page has loaded, a minute or more. We can see that appended markup on the page but the query against the '#' selector always returns zero.

Comment: So [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j0m5jj1u/1/) is happening to you? (notice setTimeout).